# The module creator for Magento gives me a blank page when seeing the admin page for it

Tags: magento

I am using [Shell's module creator](https://github.com/shell/Magento-Module-Creator) and when I load up the `Brands.php` block for the admin panel to CRUD my custom database for my module, I am given a blank page upon clicking `Manage Items` from the Brand menu. Have you any idea why? I checked the error logs and there's nothing there.

[image: blank module page]

Comment: A blank page sounds like a PHP crash, do you have error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors enabled?? And have you checked the php error log?

Comment: There is no error log. Check the updated question for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image it looks like the Grid_Container isn't getting loaded into your layout. Try [enabling Template / Block hints](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel) and seeing if there is anything loaded. I'm guessing your layout is misconfigured/missing.